# Calculate the price of nontypical option

Tags: probability, finance, stochastic-analysis

I would like to solve below exercise but got stuck. Please kindly help me. The exercise is taken from the actuarial exam organized in my country, and my translation of the exercise into English is not perfect, however I hope it's understood.

> Suppose that we are given a stock A on the Black-Scholes market. Assume that we are able to buy and sell European call options for A. We denote the price of A at the moment $T$ by $S_T$. At the moment $t=0$ we are building the portfolio in such a way that the pay-off at the moment $t=1$ is the following:
>   $W_{1}=\left\{ 
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 0 & \text{if }S_{1}\notin \lbrack 50,250] \\ 
> S_{1}-50 & \text{if }S_{1}\in \lbrack 50,100] \\ 
> 50 & \text{if }S_{1}\in \lbrack 100,200] \\ 
> 250-S_{1} & \text{if }S_{1}\in \lbrack 200,250]%
> \end{array}%
> \right. $
>
> Calculate the price $C$ of the portfolio at $T=0$ under the assumptions that $r=2\%$, $\sigma=2\%$, $S_0 = 150$.

My work so far: as $W_1=(S_1-50)^+ -(S_1-100)^+ - (S_1 - 200)^+ +(S_1 - 250)^+$, the price $C$ I am looking for is equal(?) to $C=C(50)+C(250)-C(100)-C(200)$, where $C(K)$ denotes the European call option for $A$ with a strike $K$. I suppose that the last equality is wrong and on the right side we have $\infty - \infty$(?) Could you please help? The right answer is approximately 49 - that's all I know.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your analysis?  Looks good...you have reconstructed $W_1$ as a portfolio of long and short calls.

Comment: When I try to use Black-Scholes formula to $C(50)+C(250)-C(100)-C(200)$, I obtain formula dependent on e.g. $N(55.94)+N(-24.53)-N(21.28)-N(-13.37)$, where $N$ - the normal distribution function. Values 55.94, -24.53,... are to far from zero to give any reasonable values $N$. As a result I obtain $C=0$. But maybe my mistake lies in the earlier part of my solution?

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Take $C(50)$ for example,  That is deep in the money so it's price should be the value of the forward trade (roughly).  You don't say the maturity, let's say it's a year.  That makes the forward price of the asset $(1+.02)150=153$ so the option should cost about $103$.  A little more because you are spared the loss if the stock truly tanks.  That's the most expensive option.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to discount.  That cancels the factor of $1+.02$ so the option ought to cost around $100$.   I just ran it and got $100.005$.  Note:  $2\%$ vol is very low.  Never saw a stock with such low volatility.

Comment: Back of the envelope:  since the vol is effectively $0$ all these options are just equal to their intrinsic value.  That makes the answer $100+0-50-0=50$.

Comment: Thank you lulu for our discussion. Thanks to it I understood that my solution was right and the valid answer is 49=exp(-0.02) 50.